# Images imported as symbol through Picture Maker have backgrounds using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, point, symbology, png

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I am attempting to upload a PNG image (Turbine 1 attachment) as a point symbol, however anytime I try to do this the image has either a fully white or black background.

I have made the background of the image transparent using both MS Paind 3D and a website and neither have worked.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are the precise and detailed steps that you performed to get the result you think is unexpected?

Comment: Image background removal:
- Open image in MS Paint 3d
- Using Magic Marker, remove the background.
- Save as the new image checking the symbology box.
- In ArcGIS Pro, open the symbology tab for the point feature, properties, layers, change the symbology to picture maker.
- Insert picture from file. Insert the transparent background png created earlier.
- Apply.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications and/or any relevant additional information.